# How do I compile swift without any dynamic libraries?

Tags: swift, xcode6, llvm, emscripten, asm.js

Tring to make a "hello, world" style program to see if I can use [Swift](http://swiftlang.eu/) on the web by running it through [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) to get [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) output.

The problem is that when I compile it, its bitcode tries to link dynamic libraries. It doesn't seem like it should need to do this, or it seems like someone who understands how all these pieces fit together could tell me how to provide the file it needs (I'm willing to implement some of the functions it depends on in JavaScript, if necessary).

I have a more comprehensive explanation of the environment [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/2427#issuecomment-59714913), but this is the basics:

**The file:**

```
$ cat f.swift
var message = 1
```

**Compile it to bitcode:**

```
$ xcrun swiftc -emit-bc f.swift -o f.bc
```

**Fail to compile the bitcode to asm.js:**

```
$ emcc f.bc
WARNING: Linking two modules of different data layouts: '/Users/josh/.emscripten_cache/libc.bc' is 'e-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-p:32:32:32-v128:32:128-n32-S128' whereas '/Users/josh/deleteme/swift-play/f.bc' is 'e-m:o-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128'
WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples: /Users/josh/.emscripten_cache/libc.bc' is 'asmjs-unknown-emscripten' whereas '/Users/josh/deleteme/swift-play/f.bc' is 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0'
Unknown specifier in datalayout string
UNREACHABLE executed at /Users/clb/emscripten-fastcomp/lib/IR/DataLayout.cpp:300!
0  opt                      0x00000001086d04ae llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 46
1  opt                      0x00000001086d07bb PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 27
2  opt                      0x00000001086d0b4c SignalHandler(int) + 412
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8b0e35aa _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6492d380 _sigtramp + 3649347056
5  opt                      0x00000001086d07eb raise + 27
6  opt                      0x00000001086d08a2 abort + 18
7  opt                      0x000000010865a7a6 llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) + 198
8  opt                      0x0000000108416b74 llvm::DataLayout::parseSpecifier(llvm::StringRef) + 2804
9  opt                      0x0000000108415c57 llvm::DataLayout::init(llvm::StringRef) + 471
10 opt                      0x000000010749b47e llvm::DataLayout::DataLayout(llvm::StringRef) + 158
11 opt                      0x0000000107482ba5 llvm::DataLayout::DataLayout(llvm::StringRef) + 37
12 opt                      0x000000010747943c main + 3756
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff8a2865fd start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Users/josh/code/emsdk_portable/clang/e1.25.0_64bit/opt /var/folders/7g/mbft22555w3_2nqs_h1kbglw0000gn/T/tmp93OFuV/a.out.bc -strip-debug -internalize -internalize-public-api-list=main,malloc,free -globaldce -pnacl-abi-simplify-preopt -pnacl-abi-simplify-postopt -enable-emscripten-cxx-exceptions -o /var/folders/7g/mbft22555w3_2nqs_h1kbglw0000gn/T/tmp93OFuV/a.out.bc.opt.bc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josh/code/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.25.0/emcc", line 1224, in <module>
    shared.Building.llvm_opt(final, link_opts)
  File "/Users/josh/code/emsdk_portable/emscripten/1.25.0/tools/shared.py", line 1357, in llvm_opt
    assert os.path.exists(target), 'Failed to run llvm optimizations: ' + output
AssertionError: Failed to run llvm optimizations:
```

Comment: Any new progress here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're out of luck here. The IR compiler is generating is not standard - it includes some private Apple changes which were not upstreamed (in particular, the data layout string is non-standard at least).

And no, it is not trying to link any dynamic libraries. It tries to link statically (at LLVM IR level) all necessary stuff, in particular, C standard library.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll put Swift off for a year or so, then. Just can't motivate myself to learn a language with such narrow application. Maybe Rust will get here soon.